# List one object in another controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do something in a new Rails application.

I have an app where a User has one Profile. When he is filling out his profile, he has to select which school he goes to.

I have a list of schools which is in another controller called Institutions.

I just would like to list all the institutions on that Form of the Profile controller using a select tag.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: when you display form profile controller new method will call at that time access all the  Institutions record and use it in form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way how to display the dropdown with institutions list on profile form is to use collection_select helper of the form object in your view:

```
<%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.collection_select(:institution_id, Institutions.all, :id, :name) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collection_select` method.

```
= form_for @profile do |f|
  = f.collection_select : institution_id, Institutions.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, class: 'your-css-class'
```

It is better to initialise and pass in a list of institutions to your view so that you can change the filtering logic later without affecting your views.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
    @institusions = Institutions.where(your: 'filter').all
  end
end

# In your views/profiles/new.html.haml
= form_for @profile do |f|
  = f.collection_select : institution_id, @institusions, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, class: 'your-css-class'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just using form_for or are you using simple_form?

If you are using form_for:

`<%= f.collection_select(:institution_id, Institution.all, :id, :name) %>`

where `institution_id` is the foreign key of Institution to Profile.

If you are using simple_form:

`<%= f.input :institution_id, :as => :select, :collection => Institution.all %>`